# how to use use more than one list views in scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, scrollview

basically i'm creating a profile for a user which can have his education and experience as well. these values can be multiple so i have used list views for them enclosed them in relative layout and then in scroll view. the problem is when total size increases full screen size scroll view height does not increase.

here is my xml code. and for the height of list views i'm increasing height of their respective relative layout that is working fine but problem is with scrollview

Code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="false" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_main_r"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/profile_list_button"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/profile_edit_buttons"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/profile_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_experience_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_main_r"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_exp_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/drawer_user_img"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_experience" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exp_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_exp_icon"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="@string/experience"
            android:textColor="@color/dodger_blue"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/profile_experience_button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/profile_edit_buttons"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/profile_experience_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/profile_exp_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_education_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_experience_main"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_edu_icon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/drawer_user_img"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_education" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_education_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_edu_icon"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/education"
            android:textColor="@color/dodger_blue"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/profile_education_button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/profile_edit_buttons"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/profile_education_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/profile_edu_icon"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/project_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/profile_education_main"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_design"
        android:text="@string/view_projects"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why don't you got for expandable list?

Comment: You can move the other `ListView` in the other `Tab` or do what @Saqib has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use ListView inside scroll view because listview already contains a scrollview.